# Only getting the first value of the array in a datalayer

Tags: javascript

```
<script>
for(X=0;X<OrderDetails.length;X++) {
  var transactionProducts = [
      {
        'sku': OrderDetails[X][2],
        'name': OrderDetails[X][3],
        'category': 'none',
        'price': OrderDetails[X][5],
        'quantity': OrderDetails[X][6]
      }];
 }
  dataLayer.push({'transactionProducts': transactionProducts});
</script>
```

This code is not properly executed. Also, if I put it on the Custom HTML tag inside GTM, it says `identifier expected`. Can you let me know what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Could you please create a jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/) giving the same error you're encountering ?

Comment: I couldn't replicate it on jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to be careful that all these values always exist or at least wrap each push in a try/catch. But the direct problem with your code is that there are no array comprehensions in JS, so your code should be:

```js
//<![CDATA[ 

var transactionProducts = [];
  
for(X=0;X<OrderDetails.length;X++) {
  transactionProducts.push({
    'sku': OrderDetails[X][2],
    'name': OrderDetails[X][3],
    'category': 'none',
    'price': OrderDetails[X][5],
    'quantity': OrderDetails[X][6]
  });
}


dataLayer.push({'transactionProducts': transactionProducts});

//]]>
```

Comment: Here it is in a a jsfiddle for instance, http://jsfiddle.net/11oLow9a/ but of course you would need to add the <script></script> if this is a custom html tag..

Comment: Since you are including it directly into HTML you probably need a CDATA block (added in my example,) I don't think that is an issue if you let GTM include them as custom tags though.

Comment: What does this have to do with array comprehensions?

Comment: If you look at the code in the original question (before the last edit) it is written in the form of a list comprehension.